# Add a unique listener to all elements in a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible via javascript or jQuery to add a unique event listener to all elements of a class so that when an event is triggered is is triggered for only that element and not all elements having the same class name?

For example, if I have the following HTML

```
<div class"clickable-box"><span style="display: none;">Hi There!</span></div>
<div class"clickable-box"><span style="display: none;">Peek-A-Boo!</span></div>
<div class"clickable-box"><span style="display: none;">Now You See Me!</span></div>
```

...and the following jQuery

```
$('.clickable-box').click(function() {
    $('.clickable-box span').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

...the above will toggle the reveal the span for all the divs.

Is there a way to make these trigger individually without having to use a unique id or class for each div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need

```
$('.clickable-box').click(function() {
    $(this).find('span').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Also missing `=` after `class` in the div

```
<div class="clickable-box"><span style="display: none;">Hi There!</span></div>
<div class="clickable-box"><span style="display: none;">Peek-A-Boo!</span></div>
<div class="clickable-box"><span style="display: none;">Now You See Me!</span></div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kHvRL/)

Answer (score 2):

You should specify a [context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery) when you search for the span:

```
$('.clickable-box').click(function(){
    $('span', this).slideToggle('slow');
});
```